# how to create a module for segmoid function on VB?

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods

I have tried this

```
 Module module1
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function sigmoid(ByRef x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Integer
        y = 1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-x))
        Return y
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Module
```

and when I want to call it I use

```
 y3 = (x1 * w13 + x2 * w23 - seta3).sigmoid
```

I just want to put x as (x1 * w13 + x2 * w23 - seta3)
and get the y value of it 
it is related to neural network 
but I got an error always .. what is the wrong ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see several things I would change for the Sigmoid function:

```
Public Module module1
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function Sigmoid(ByRef x As Integer) As Double
        Return 1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-x))
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function Sigmoid(ByRef x As Double) As Double
        Return 1 / (1 + Math.Exp(-x))
    End Function
End Module
```

1. Extensions methods tend to work better when the Module is `Public`. Otherwise, you might not see the method available when you need it.
2. `Return Nothing` had no meaning, as it directly followed another return statement.
3. The `y` input to the function was never used, so don't ask for it.
4. You need a `Double`, rather than an `Integer` for the return type. It's unlikely that a division expression with a `1` for the first term will ever result in an workable Integer.
5. This means you also want to use `Double` for the `y3` variable, and that in turn makes we wonder how many other values here should really be doubles, hence the overloaded method.

Now you can call it like this:

```
y3 = (x1 * w13 + x2 * w23 - seta3).Sigmoid()
```

Note that in VB.Net, it's a best practice to always use the `()` notation when calling a function. This is not required, but still a good habit to have. This is a change from older VB6/VBA/VBScript code, where using parentheses had undesirable side effects in some cases.

Comment: +1 for not down voting a "not-well formed" question, and trying to understand the question. This is rare these days :)

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn , thank you for explaining for me I appreciate your time and effort

Comment: @Makketronix I can't get what you mean :)

Comment: @AlKobtan, Joel did good job in trying to understand what you mean. Normally you would post the error you are getting. That comment was mainly for him :)

Comment: @Makketronix, really what he did is rare :)